# Integration By Parts to Prove the Interpolation Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

> Integrate by parts to prove the interpolation inequality:
>   $$
> ||Du||_{L_2}\leq C||u||^{1/2}_{L^2} ||D^2 u||^{1/2}_{L^2},
> $$
>   for all $u \in C_0^{\infty}(U),$ where $U$ is some open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n.$

I am incredibly weak in multivariable situations and have no idea what to do any help would be appreciated.

It would be extremely helpful if somebody knew of a place where I could read what the integration of parts formula was in this situation.

Comment: Is $u$ real valued, or is it allowed to have complex values?

Comment: $u$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This exercise can be found in Chapter 5 of the [Evans book](http://tinyurl.com/nrlpf5t). To understand the notations $\|Du\|_{L^2}$ and $\|D^2u\|_{L^2}$, see Appendix A.3. And for the "integration by parts formula", see Appendix C (Theorem 2). Also, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258168/question-from-evans-pde-book), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818788/int-u-du2-leq-int-u-u21-2-int-u-d2-u2-1-2-for-u-in-h1) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369989/question-9-chap-5-evans-pde).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably what it's getting at is this:
$$ \lVert Du \rVert_2^2 = \int_U \partial_i u \partial_i u = -\int_U u \partial_i \partial_i u, $$
using the fact that $u \in C_0^{\infty}(U)$ to discard the boundary terms (there are $n$ of them, and they all look like $[ u \partial_i u ]_{\partial U}$.)
Then applying Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$ \left\lvert \int_U (-u) \partial_i \partial_i u \right\rvert \leqslant \lVert -u \rVert_2 \left\lvert \int_U (\partial_i \partial_i u)^2 \right\rvert^{1/2}  $$
The last factor's integrand is smaller than
$$ \lvert D^2 u \rvert^2 = \sum_{i,j} (\partial_i \partial_j u)^2, $$
and hence
$$ \lVert Du \rVert_2^2 \leqslant \lVert u \rVert_2 \lVert D^2 u \rVert_2, $$
and the result follows by taking a square root.

Comment: Thanks! I was really lost as to what was meant by the integration by parts formula since our integral involved $Du$. So this helped.

Comment: In the first line the LHS is always positive since it's a norm, but the RHS can be negative if $u$ is positive everywhere.